# Powershell Count how often an Event ID occurs in a Windows log, limited by a date range

Tags: powershell, event-log

I want to count how often an Event ID occurs in a specific Windows log, limited by a date range.

Eg Event ID 7042 in Application Log, Errors only,  in July

Answer (score 1):

#enter your local date format e.g. UK is dd/mm/yyyy

```
$Begin = Get-Date -Date '07/01/2022 00:00:00'
$End   = Get-Date -Date '01/08/2022 00:00:00'
```

/#
Level
Verbose                        5
Informational                  4
Warning                        3
Error                          2
Critical                       1
#/

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='Application'; Level=2; Id =7042; StartTime=$Begin; EndTime=$End}).count
```